# Find the complex integral over a function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I need to find
$$
\int_\gamma{\Im zdz}
$$
where $\gamma = \{x, y: y=2x^2, 0\le x\le1\}$.
I have no clue how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the obvious parameterization of your curve: $\gamma(x) = x + 2x^2i$ for $x \in [0,1]$, and since $\Im z = \Im x+iy = y$ you will have to
$$
\int_\gamma (\Im z)dz = \int_{x=0}^{x=1} \Im (x + 2x^2i)dx = \int_0^1 2x^2dx.
$$
Can you finish this?

Comment: Ah that's how! It's 2/3, thanks.

Comment: You can't so easily change from $dz$ to $dx$.

Comment: @Arthur i thought i am just parameterizing a curve -- how do you suggest to make it more correct

Comment: But when parameterising a curve to integrate, you have to take into account how fast the parametrisation moves along the curve.

Comment: @Arthur please elaborate how to turn $dz$ into $dx$